# Store data for web articles

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Im trying to design a table to hold data for web pages. I have three types of web pages each with slightly different design so require slightly different data, some have thumb images and other do not, some have sub titles and others do not.

Im trying to store the data in one table:

```
id | title | subtitle | thumb | article | created_at | updated_at | published
```

But as mentioned earlier some articles do not have a subtitle or a thumb so in some rows these would be blank, which is not great table design.

What would be the best approach to this? I don't really want to have 3 separate tables as the majority of the information is the same across all tables.

Comment: How sparse do you expect the table to be?  Having, say, 10% of a few columns being `null` is not necessarily bad design.

Comment: The table will probably end up having a 1000 rows.

Comment: No...I'm trying to gage how often the `subtitle`and `thumb` fields will be `null`.  Also, when you query your original table do you expect that you will always or at least often be needing the `subtitle` and `thumb` fields?

Comment: a third of my articles will need a thumb, a third will need a subtitle and a third will need both, when querying the table I will select * that belong to a specific category id

Comment: If each article will truly only appear once in your original table, then I would probably leave the design as is.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I always thought it was a bad idea to have null columns but thanks for your insights.

Comment: By going with the NULL approach, you are somewhat enforcing a similar "look and feel" for each of your page types.  This is favorable.